# Modifying the Rails Object for the seed process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, seed

Is it possible to modify the Rails obj?

I only want to modify it briefly and change it back.

My Reasoning:
I am trying to work on my seeds file and make it a little more robust.

In my model there is a process that looks at the current controller and the current user, it tracks this user during there session.

It throws an error though during my seed tests because there is no controller based user session.

What I wanted  to do was to add 

`Rails.seed = true`

at the start of my seed, it would get to the model and in the model I would wrap a control flow(if statement) for this property around the block that setups up tracking.

Then I would remove 

`Rails.seed = true`

 at the end of the seed file.

Comment: If you want different behavior between when you run the tests and regular runtime, why not use an environment variable? `Rails.env['seeding']`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting it directly on the `Rails` object, you can use [custom configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration)

**config/initializers/custom_config.rb** (name unimportant, just in an initializer)

```
Rails.configuration.seeding = false
```

**db/seeds.rb**

```
Rails.configuration.seeding = true

User.create
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # just as an example
  after_initialize do
    if Rails.configuration.seeding
      puts "Seeding DB"
    else
      puts "Normal"
    end
  end
end
```

**output**

```
$ bin/rake db:seed
# Running via Spring preloader in process 19017
# Seeding DB
$ bin/rails c
User.create
# Normal
# => #<User ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend modifying the Rails class but to achieve that you could do something like:

```
class Rails
  attr_accessor :seeding

  def seeding=(bool)
    @seeding = bool
  end

  def seeding?
    @seeding ||= false
  end
end
```

Then you could use `Rails.seeding = true` to set it and `Rails.seeding?` to access it. Also it will default to false if it is unset.

Another solution might be wrapping the part that is blowing up in a `being` `rescue` block to catch the error.